# Linq to sql with union

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two similar queries and need to apply union to them.
Part of first query looks like this:

```
var query1 = from contract in ContractRepo.GetAll()
(lots of joins)
select new ContractViewModel(){
(lots of fields)     
Attachments = null
}
```

Part of second query:

```
var query2 = from com in CommRepo.GetAll()
join comAtt in AttachmentRepo.GetAll() on   
com.Id equals comAtt.comId into att
select new ContractViewModel(){
(lots of fields),
Attachment = from a in att
    select new AttachmentViewModel()
    {
    (some fields)
    }
}

var query = query1.Union(query2);
```

The problem is with Attachment field which is of type IEnumerable. 
I cannot assign null or initialize empty list because I get exception. I cannot remove this field from first query because the union wont work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I get exception" Which exception?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize property with default value and do not set null:

```
class ContractViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<AttachmentViewModel> Attachments {get; set;} = Enumerable.Empty<AttachmentViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Ok but when I remove Attachment from first query then Union will not work

Comment: @drv in query1 and query2 you select `ContractViewModel` as I see, so I don't understand, why union does not work

Comment: When I remove Attachments from first query it doesn't work because Attachments are still in second query. So I get "two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query" message.